# How to return duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I have SQL Server.
For example I have such query:

```
select playerid, fullname
from players
where playerid in (123,123,1234,1234,1234)
```

How I can make to return at result duplicates, I mean at this example - return twice record for player 123 and 3 times record for player 1234. (I have a long select with big list of playerIDs)

Comment: Could you please edit your question and share some simple data and the expected output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you appear to be trying to do is duplicate rows from your `players` table based on a list of specific `playerid` values.

To do this like you're trying to do in your example you can join to a list of values, like this:

```
select playerid, fullname 
from players p
join (
  values(123),(123),(1234),(1234),(1234)
)x(PlayerId) on p.PlayerId = x.PlayerId;
```

Comment: This one worked, thank you!